# Why socket pointers are used everywhere instead of socket instances?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, pointers

I'm new to C++/QT programming and I can't find an answer.
I saw a lot of examples/questions/conversations and almost everywhere people use tcp socket pointers.
If something goes wrong, users close socket, delete it and create another one.

Why not just use socket instance, close it, configure and try to connect it again with new parameters? Does it gives some unobvious profit to use pointers and recreate socket every time?

Comment: Qt classes sometimes have a pretty deep inheritance hierarchy, with many virtual functions and polymorphism. For polymorphism to work you need either pointers or references. And since C++ doesn't have a "null value", it's easier to use pointers as then a null pointer could be used to indicate failure of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important reason to use pointers instead instances when you work with Qt classes is [Qt Ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html). It helps you in memory management and it requires objects to be created in heap.